# Get MIN, MAX values from a linking table

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 3 tables in a MYSQL DB

ORDER

```
   order_id | order_date
-------------------------
      1     | 2021-09-20    
      2     | 2021-09-21
```

PRODUCTS

```
   product_id | product_price
-------------------------
      1     | 30    
      2     | 34
      3     | 39
      4     | 25
```

ORDER_PRODUCTS

```
   product_id | order_id
-------------------------
      1     | 1    
      2     | 1 
      1     | 2    
      4     | 2
```

Now I want to know the min and max prices of all products in a specific order when I give a specific product id group by order_id.

EX:

```
order_id | min_price         | max_price
-----------------------------------------
      1  | 30(p_id=1)        | 34(p_id=2)
      2  | 25(p_id=4)        | 30(p_id=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following:

```sql
    SELECT
        op.order_id,
        MIN(p.product_price) as min_price,
        MAX(p.product_price) as max_price
    FROM
        ORDER_PRODUCTS op
    INNER JOIN
        PRODUCTS p ON op.product_id = p.product_id
    GROUP BY 
        op.order_id
```

#### EDIT 1

As it pertains to

> Now I want to know the min and max prices of all products in a
> specific order

You may use a where clause to only consider a specific order

```sql
    SELECT
        op.order_id,
        MIN(p.product_price) as min_price,
        MAX(p.product_price) as max_price
    FROM
        ORDER_PRODUCTS op
    WHERE
        op.order_id = <insert order id here>
    INNER JOIN
        PRODUCTS p ON op.product_id = p.product_id
    GROUP BY 
        op.order_id
```

or if it is that you would like to determine the min and max prices for orders that have a particular product, you may modify your where clause as below to use an IN with a subquery

```sql
    SELECT
        op.order_id,
        MIN(p.product_price) as min_price,
        MAX(p.product_price) as max_price
    FROM
        ORDER_PRODUCTS op
    WHERE
        op.order_id IN (
             SELECT inc.order_id
             FROM ORDER_PRODUCTS inc
             WHERE inc.product_id = <insert product id here>
        )
    INNER JOIN
        PRODUCTS p ON op.product_id = p.product_id
    GROUP BY 
        op.order_id
```

or simply by using a having clause with a case statement to filter

```sql
    SELECT
        op.order_id,
        MIN(p.product_price) as min_price,
        MAX(p.product_price) as max_price
    FROM
        ORDER_PRODUCTS op
    INNER JOIN
        PRODUCTS p ON op.product_id = p.product_id
    GROUP BY 
        op.order_id
    HAVING 
        SUM(
            CASE WHEN op.product_id = <insert product id here> THEN 1 END
        ) > 0
```

NB. Please replace `<insert product id here>` and `<insert order id here>` with actual values while testing.

[View working demo db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qDwfdEu5bH8fNxC1mjaB7Z/0)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response @ggordon, but here I need only the orders that include a specific product (take it as product_id=1).

Comment: Use WHERE clause

Comment: @RahulBiswas when I add a where clause it's giving me the min and max values of the entire products table, but I only need the min-max values of the products that are in the order. I'll update the question, then you'll clearly understand.

Comment: ok @AchyuthKodali please update question.

Comment: please check the required output table and product table. @RahulBiswas

Comment: @AchyuthKodali will u show the concatenation product price with product id? Given query is OK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237364/discussion-between-achyuth-kodali-and-rahul-biswas).

Comment: @AchyuthKodali I've updated the answer with additional scenarios, working demo db fiddle and considerations. If this does not help, please provide additional scenarios and sample results in your question and I will update and test against there. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @ggordon thank you very much, the query with 'HAVING' clause works.